# Direct construction of covariance matrix in R

Tags: r, covariance

I have 2 vectors

```
s1=seq(0,10,length.out=25)
s2=seq(0,4,length.out=10)
```

and I want to establish a covariance matrix based on teh function

```
covariance=function(s1,s2) {(s1-s2)^2}
```

How can I do this without a for loop in R

Comment: No they do not need to be the same length

Comment: Yes true, the comment below answers my question , Thank you

Comment: You can use these methods as long as you understand you should use the term `'covariance'` to refer to the results when talking with anyone who actually understands statistics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use the sapply function

```
sapply(s1,covariance,s2,H)
```

This does not need a for loop